# JavaScript Separator

Tags: javascript, django

I want to receive data from DJANGO and change HTML VALUE according to the data with JAVASCRIPT.
BUT JAVASCRIPT not work. I'll send you what I've made up. I don't know what's wrong

##django view

```
def message(msg):

    time.sleep(1)
    return f'{msg} '

def get_data():

    status_code =['AB','CD','EF','GH','IJ']
    for i in status_code:
        time.sleep(0.5)
        print(i)
        yield message(i)

def test_stream(request):

    stream = get_data()
    # stream = db_restore_test()
    response = StreamingHttpResponse(stream, status=200, content_type='text/event-stream')
    response['Cache-Control'] = 'no-cache'
    return response

def jobs(request):

    return render(request, 'jobs/index.html')
```

#html (javascript)

```
    const arr = oEvent.target.responseText.split(' ')
    log(arr.reverse()[1])
    const data = arr.reverse()[1]
    if (data == 'AB'){
        document.getElementById('step1_status').innerHTML = '시작';
        log('1')
    }
    else if (data == 'CD'){
        document.getElementById('step1_status').innerHTML = '완료';
        document.getElementById('step2_status').innerHTML = '시작';
        log('2')
    }
    else if (data == 'EF'){
        document.getElementById('step2_status').innerHTML = '완료';
        document.getElementById('step3_status').innerHTML = '시작';
        log('3')
    }
    else if (data == 'GH'){
        document.getElementById('step3_status').innerHTML = '완료';
        document.getElementById('step4_status').innerHTML = '시작';
        log('4')
    }
    else if (data == 'IJ'){
        document.getElementById('step4_status').innerHTML = '완료';
        log('5')
    }
}
```

## WEB Console

[image]

I dont understand why result only '2'.

Comment: Can you please share how `test_stream` is called from Javascript?

Comment: ok. i show you whole script.

Comment: sorry. The original was not edited, so I left it here

        let xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        url = '{% url "jobs:test_stream" %}';
        xmlhttp.addEventListener('load', reqListener);
        xmlhttp.addEventListener('progress', updateProgress, false);
        xmlhttp.open("get", url, true);
        xmlhttp.send();